# Java Hashmap XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, hashmap

I'm working with XML files which are a printout of a Java HashMap, like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<java version="1.7.0_05" class="java.beans.XMLDecoder">
<object class="java.util.HashMap">
 <void method="put">
  <string>ENTRY</string>
  <string>01/02/2002</string>
 </void>
 <void method="put">
  <string>DOC</string>
  <long>3315959</long>
 </void>
 <void method="put">
  <string>DOC_CLASS_NUMBER</string>
  <int>4</int>
 </void>
 <void method="put">
  <string>ACCESS_PRIV</string>
  <string>3,18,81</string>
 </void>
</object>
</java>
```

I need to load the elements into an MS Access data base. So i'm looking into XSLT to transform the xml so I would get something like the following (so import into ms access would be possible):

```
  <file>
   <Entry>01/02/2002</entry>
   <DOC>1335959</DOC>  
   <DOC_CLASS_NUMBER>4</DOC_CLASS_NUMBER>
   <ACCESS_RIGHTS>3,18,81</ACCESS_RIGHTS>
  </file>
```

I've been trying this,since I can't adress the parent nodes (I think) but I only retrieve the first element:

```
<xsl:for-each select="*">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="//string[1]"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="//string[1]/following-sibling::*"/></td>
  </tr>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

Any Ideas how I can solve this?

Comment: Will each `void` element end up in a separate XML file, containing a single `file` element?

Comment: No, every <object class="java.util.HashMap"> is one complete instance (or file) which needs to be loaded into msaccess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really have a hard time understanding why the tiny code snippet you show outputs HTML elements, if the output you expect has nothing to do with HTML.

**XSLT Stylesheet**

Match `object` and output a `file` element. Then, match `void` in general and define another template for `ACCESS_PRIV`, since there the name of the output element cannot be deducted from the input.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="object">
      <file>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </file>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="void">
        <xsl:element name="{string[1]}">
            <xsl:value-of select="*[2]"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="void[string[1] = 'ACCESS_PRIV']">
        <ACCESS_RIGHTS>
            <xsl:value-of select="*[2]"/>
        </ACCESS_RIGHTS>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**XML Output**

This is *almost* the same as your expected output, since your expected output is malformed XML. Be careful, XML is case-sensitive and `Entry` is not the same as `entry`.

```
<file>
   <ENTRY>01/02/2002</ENTRY>
   <DOC>3315959</DOC>
   <DOC_CLASS_NUMBER>4</DOC_CLASS_NUMBER>
   <ACCESS_RIGHTS>3,18,81</ACCESS_RIGHTS>
</file>
```

Comment: This is perfect, my example wasn't very clear indeed, I was using the w3schools xslt tool and I only changed the xpath's to validate output. (but I don't need HTML output) Thank you very much, It's obvious I still have a lot to learn in XLST but you helped me a great deal! thanks